# Post request with ajax does not enter in success statement

Tags: ajax

I have a little problem with a post request on a rest api.I'm tryng to add data into a database,and the operation succeed but the code does not enter in the success part,but it goes in error and the error code is 204(No Content) that is correct since I'm performing a POST. The question is why it goes in error? here is the xml file

```
 <cities>
   <city>
       <cityPK>
           <name>Guidonia</name>
           <region>Lazio</region>
       </cityPK>
   </city>
   <city>
       <cityPK>
           <name>Milano</name>
           <region>Lombardia</region>
       </cityPK>
   </city>
   <city>
       <cityPK>
           <name>Roma</name>
           <region>Lazio</region>
       </cityPK>
   </city>
```

and this is the post call

```
 var url1 = "http://localhost:8080/RestService/webresources/entities.city";
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                data : "<city><cityPK> <name>Tivoli</name><region>Lazio</region></cityPK></city>",
                url: url1 ,
                contentType : "application/xml",
                success: function(res){
                   alert("it works!");
                },
               error: function(res){
                    alert("error message :" + res.status);
                    }     
            });
        });
```

the alert("it works") is never done,but the data is insert into db.Any suggestions? Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: This code is ok. May be your rest service isnt returning anything. Have you tried to see if the service actually works?

Comment: Yes the service works well,and my data is added,so I do not expect anything in return,but since the call succeds the code should alert "it works!" shouldn't it? @P.Jairaj

Comment: No, it should return something. Even if its empty like {}. Thats what the error is. It is expecting xml but gets empty string. You should try to pass some default xml.

Comment: Ok,where?Could you tell me what I've to modify?thanks!